# Teste unitario en Python de acceso a datos en AtlasDB

Tags: python, testing, fastapi

estoy tratando de crear un test para una funcion de un repo que accede a un servicio, y este a una BBDD de AtlasDB. Aún mockeando la función del service, si no uso un dato que ya exista realemente en la BBDD, el test falla. Estoy testeandoq ue el usuario exsita en la BBDD.

Este es mi test:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from api.users.service.users.users_repository import search_user_exist

class TestUsersRepository(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('api.users.service.users.users_service.db_find_one')
    def test_to_know_if_a_user_exists_and_if_it_does_exist(
        self, 
        mock_db_find_one
    ):
        user_email = "johndoe@mail.com" # -> este correo debe existir en la BBDD para que el test funcione
        mock_db_find_one.return_value = {'email', user_email}
                
        result = search_user_exist('email', user_email)
        self.assertTrue(result, 'Expected True, but got {}'.format(result))
```

Esta es la función del repo:

```py
def search_db_user(field: str, key: any):
    try:
        user = db_find_one(field, key)
        print(f'user_serach: {user}')
        return UserDB(**user_schema_db(user))
    except:
        return {'error': "Error al buscar al usuario {}".format(key)}
```

y esta la función del service:

```py
def _users() -> MongoClient: 
    return db_client.users

def db_find_one(field: str, key: str):
    return _users().find_one({field: key})
```

Gracias.